# How does hash table get(key) works when multiple keys are stored with linked nodes?

Tags: data-structures, hashtable

I am aware how hash table works. But I am not sure of the possible implementation of get(key) when multiple values are stored at the same place with the help of linked list.
For example:
 set(1,'Val1') get stored at index 7
 set(2,'Val2') also get stored at index 7. (Internal implementation create a linked list and store pointer at index 7. That's understandable).

But I am thinking if now I call get(2). How does Hash Table knows which Value to return. Because my hash function will resolve this to index 7. But at index 7 there are 2 values.
One possible way is to store at the linked node, both value and key.
Is there any other different implementation possible?

Answer (score 1):

Go through the linked list and do a linear search for the key '2'. The properties of the hash function and the hash table size should guarantee that these lists' length is O(1) on average.

I think you misunderstood the fact that hash tables has to store their keys. The hash function is only for speeding up insertion/lookup.

Comment: I think you are right. I got misunderstood a bit. They have to store key and value.